# how to reduce size of the canvas window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I want to reduce the size of height received from following code :

```
var pageHeight = $('[data-role="page"]').height();
```

I have tried as following :

```
 var newHeight=(pageHeight)-50px;
 $('#map-canvas').css({'height':newHeight});
```

I am not able to get the newHeight.

Comment: When you change the height of a canvas via the CSS style, the canvas will keep its internal resolution, but will be rescaled by the browser to fit the new size. As a result the canvas will look blurred. To avoid this, change the width and height attributes of the canvas HTML node itself.

Comment: What's your HTML and CSS structure?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `:` from the jquery and use `,` and `{..}` are not needed.

try this.

```
var newHeight=(pageHeight)-50px;
$('#map-canvas').css('height',newHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**`height()`**](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
$('#map-canvas').height(newHeight);
```

Comment: ...and then the #map-canvas will be cleared, so be sure you also redraw everything that was on it.